# Spring configuration file: placeholders

Tags: spring, embed, placeholder

Is it possible to embed a placeholder within a value string?

For example: `${database.${environment}.url}`, where `${enivronment}` is the placeholder.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${database.${environment}.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible.

See following example retrieved from the spring documentation. The answer to your question is given with the following placeholder definition: **jdbc:${dbname}**

Example XML context definition:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName"><value>${driver}</value></property>
   <property name="url"><value>jdbc:${dbname}</value></property>
 </bean>
```

Example properties file:

```
 driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 dbname=mysql:mydb
```

Source for spring documentation:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html